# sql query to check existing records

Tags: java, mysql

I have data in following format:

```
 HashMap<PageID, Set<SubscriberIDS>>
```

What I need to check is how many `SubscriberIDS` for each of the `PageIDs` do not exist in a MySQL table already. MySQL table has `PageID` and `SubscriberID` columns.

This is what I have so far:

```
String NEW_SUBSCRIBER_COUNT = "SELECT ? - COUNT(*) as new_subscribers from FB_SUBSCRIPTIONS WHERE PAGEID=? AND SUBSCRIBERID IN (?)";
```

First parameter being `numberOFSubscriberIDs`, Second being `PageId` and Third being `SubscriberIds`

but this will need to be hit for each pageId. How do I modify it to give me `number of new subscribers` for each `PageID` using single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any specific need to do it in one query? Because while it can, it might actually be more readable to use your original solution and invoke a query for each page id. In any case, what you want can't be done in a single line, so you need to expect to loop at a given point.

```
// Build dynamic query

StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder();
Iterator<PageID> it = yourMap.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
  PageID key = it.next();
  Set<SubscriberIDS> value = yourMap.get(key);

  // You need to fill the 'IN' clause with multiple parameters, one for each subscriber id
  StringBuilder inClause = new StringBuilder();
  for(SubscriberIDS subId : value){
    if(inClause.length > 0){
      inClause.append(", ");
    }
    inClause.append("?");

    preparedStatement.setInt(paramIndex++, subId.getId());
  }

  // For each page id we append a new 'OR' to our query
  if(whereClause.lenght > 0){
    whereClause.append(" OR ");
  }
  whereClause.append("(PAGEID=? AND SUBSCRIBERID IN (").append(inClause.toString()).append("))");
}

String query = "SELECT PAGEID, COUNT(SUBSCRIBERID) AS SUBSCRIBERS FROM FB_SUBSCRIPTIONS WHERE " + whereClause.toString() + " GROUP BY PAGEID";

// Create prepared statement and set parameters

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
int paramIndex = 0;
it = yourMap.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
  PageID key = it.next();
  Set<SubscriberIDS> value = yourMap.get(key);

  preparedStatement.setInt(paramIndex++, key.getId());

  for(SubscriberIDS subId : value){
    preparedStatement.setInt(paramIndex++, subId.getId());
  }
}

// Execute query, loop over result and calculate new subscriptions

ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()){
  int pageId = rs.getInt("PAGEID");
  int newSubscriptions = yourMap.get(pageId).size() - rs.getInt("SUBSCRIBERS");
  System.out.println(pageId + ", " + newSubscriptions);
}
```

Given following data in your map:

```
PAGEID  SUBSCRIBERIDS
1   1,3,4,5,9
2   3,4,5,6,8,9
3   2,5,6
```

And following data in the DB:

```
PAGEID  SUBSCRIBERIDS
1   3,4,10,11
2   1,2,5,7
3   1,2,5,6,7,8,9
```

This should give following output:

```
1,3
2,6
3,0
```

I haven't actually ran the code, so it might need some adjustments, but it gives you the general idea...

Comment: This isn't logically correct. It will give same count of new_subscribers for all page ids

Comment: Indeed, you have to use 'COUNT(SUBSCRIBERID)' instead of COUNT(*) obviously.

Comment: nup.  yourMap.get(rs.getInt("PAGEID")).size() - rs.getInt("subscribers");
}  this means size of my map - existing subscribers. that's now i am asking in question

Comment: Not really, yourMap.get(rs.getInt("PAGEID")).size() won't give you the size of your map, it will give you the size of the set of subscriberids for that given pageid. So, total nr of subscribers for that pageid - existing subscribers for that pageid = new subscribers for that pageid.

Comment: yourMap.get(rs.getInt("PAGEID")).size() - This give me number of subscribers coming in , rs.getInt("subscribers") gives me total number. where did we check if the ones that are coming in already exist in DB or not @vincent

Comment: So your map does not contain all subscriberids but can contain any number of existing/non-existing ids? That's not totally clear from the original post. I've updated my answer with a new attempt using a dynamic query.